Only IP packets are displayed. Wireshark, Scapy
I am testing my Scapy code and when sending UDP, Wireshark shows the IPv4 protocol (without the ability to view the UDP packet). How to configure Wireshark to view more than just IP packets. Or is it something else?
Wireshark:
Wireshark screen
The code:
from scapy.all import *
from random import randint

while True:
     pck1 = IP(dst="192.168.88.134", frag = randint(1, 8191), flags = "MF")/UDP(dport = 15000, sport = 15000, len = randint(1,40000), chksum =0)
     send(pck1)


By setting frag to a non-zero value you're telling Wireshark that the IP packet is a middle fragment of a larger payload. When a large payload e.g. a UDP packet is fragmented normally, its UDP header would be present only in the 1st fragment (i.e. the one with offset 0) and not repeated across every fragment.
(If you manually put a second UDP header in a non-0 fragment, after reassembly it would actually become part of the UDP data payload!)
Because of this, it wouldn't make sense for Wireshark to search for UDP headers inside fragments, and therefore it doesn't. The only useful thing it can do is search the same capture for adjacent fragments and try to reassemble them – if it finds all fragments including the offset=0 one and successfully reassembles them, then it will be able to detect UDP inside.
